# Cloned Tool doesn't work with it's script? (Roblox Studio)

Tags: lua, roblox

I've made a successfull Shop GUI that gives a cloned tool to the player whenever the price of "Tabs" is met. Though, when the tool is cloned and sent to the player's hand, it's script does not work.
I have the Shop Tools in ReplicatedStorage to help with cloning.
I've looked for many examples online and just cannot grasp the concept of RemoteEvents, which I am assuming that is what I need.

- I'm using Clone() to help with cloning.
- The "Tabs" work just fine when the Tool is purchased.
- The Cloned Tool, when used, does NOT execute it's script.
- I have tried Youtube Tutorials and looking through the Roblox Development Forum.

I am new to Roblox Studio coding, so it will be very helpful to get some advice.

I expect clear instructions, videos, or documents explaining on how I can get the Cloned Tool to execute it's script normally.

Answer (score 0):

You may be cloning it from the client, which would explain why the script (which I assume to be a server script) does not run.
Yes, you need to use RemoteEvents to communicate  to the server that the client wants to buy the item, then check from there if the player has enough money and then clone the tool to their backpack.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).